# how to call an endpoint that accepts only string value as request body parameter

Tags: java, spring, web-services, curl, postman

I have defined a method that accepts string value as a request body parameter like below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/stringParam",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String stringMethod(@RequestBody String stringParam){

        return stringParam;
    }
```

I have tried to call that endpoint with below curl command

```
curl -X POST  "http://localhost:7979/choudhury-rest/rest/book/stringParam" -d '\"ravi\"' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This has given me this error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

after that, I have tried in another way

```
curl -X POST  "http://localhost:7979/choudhury-rest/rest/book/stringParam" -d 'stringParam=\"ravi\"' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This also gave me this error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

can anyone help me that how can I call that method (i don't know whether can we define a rest method that accepts a primitive value (int, long and etc..)  as request body parameter )

Comment: Try enclosing your data with `{` and replacing `=` with `:` e.g: `-d '{"stringParam":"ravi"}'`

Comment: "i don't know whether can we define a rest method that accepts a primitive value as request body parameter" - String is not a primitive type in Java.

Answer (score 3):

I see couple of things you can change to make this work.

You have to change consumes argument in your controller, use MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE instead of MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN

```
@RequestMapping(value="/stringParam", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String stringMethod(@RequestBody String stringParam){
    return stringParam;
}
```

When using curl, define that you are sending text only by including header Content-Type: text/plain

```
$ curl -X POST  "http://localhost:8080/choudhury-rest/rest/book/stringParam" -d "ravi" -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

Results

```
$ curl -X POST  "http://localhost:8080/choudhury-rest/rest/book/stringParam" -d "ravi" -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     8  100     4  100     4   4000   4000 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8000ravi
```

Cheers!

NOTE:  I tested this controller in SpringBoot v2.0.5.RELEASE

[image]